# converting videos from flv to mp4 audio not playing

Tags: html, audio, video, ffmpeg

i want to play **flv** video file using html5 video tag so for converting flv to mp4 iam using **ffmpeg**,

`ffmpeg -y -i input.flv -strict -2 -ar 22050 -ab 512 -b 800k -f mp4 -s 514:362 -c:a aac output.mp4`

But for the above code conversion i can get the video properly but not audio is all mute. 
Please help me out for the code conversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an audio bitrate (128k in the following example):

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.flv -strict -2 -ar 22050 -ab 512 -b 800k -f mp4 -s 514:362 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot worked out for me appreciated your reply